# I am trying to build a social app, where users can post, join groups, add groups etc. but im stuck with an error

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to make a user to be able to see the group details whenever they click on the group name from the group lists, just like facebook. but the slug isn't working i am getting this error.** Reverse for 'single_group' with keyword arguments '{'slug': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['group/posts(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$']**

## group models.py

```
from django.db import models 
from django.urls import reverse 
from django.utils.text import slugify 
from django import template 
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model




register = template 
User = get_user_model()

class Group(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True) 
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True) 
    description = models.TextField(max_length=300, blank=True, default= '') 
    description_html = models.TextField(editable=False, default= '', blank=True) 
    members_field = models.ManyToManyField(User, through= 'Group_member')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        kwargs = {'slug':self.slug}
        return reverse('single-group', kwargs=kwargs)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

class Group_member(models.Model):

    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='membership', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_group', on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
    
        return self.user.username
    
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('group', 'user')
```

## group views.py

i made use of Class base view for this project

```
from typing import Any 
from django.shortcuts import render 
from django.views import generic 
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin 
from . import models 
from django.urls import reverse 
from django.contrib import messages 
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404 
from django.db import IntegrityError

class Create_group(generic.CreateView, LoginRequiredMixin):

    model = models.Group 

    fields = ('name', 'description')

class Single_group(generic.DetailView):

    model = models.Group

class Group_list(generic.ListView):

    model = models.Group 

class Join_group(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.RedirectView):

    model = models.Group
    
    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):

        return reverse('group:single', kwargs={'slug': self.kwargs.get('slug')})
    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        group = get_object_or_404(group, slug =kwargs.get('slug'))
    
        try: 

            models.Group_member.create(self.request.user, group=group)
    
        except IntegrityError:

            messages.warning(self.request, (Warning), f'you are already a member of {group.name}')
    
        else:

            messages.success(self.request,f'you are now a member of {group.name}')
    
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)



class Leave_group(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.RedirectView):

    model = models.Group
```

## group urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from . import views

app_name = 'group'

        urlpatterns = [
            path('create-group/', views.Create_group.as_view(), name='create-group'),
            re_path(r"^posts(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$", views.Single_group.as_view(), name='single_group'),
            path('', views.Group_list.as_view(), name='group-list'),
            path('join-group/<str:pk>', views.Join_group.as_view(), name='join-group'),
            path('leave-group/', views.Leave_group.as_view(), name='leave-group'), 
        ]  


        # template group_list.html
        
                {% extends 'group/group_base.html' %}
                
                {% block groupcontent %}
                
                    {% for group in object_list %}
                
                        <a href="{% url 'group:single_group' slug=group.slug %}"> {{group.name}}</a>
                
                    {% endfor %}  
                
                {% endblock %}
```